# For Stoke’s theorem on Manifolds how is the total change over the boundary generalized

Tags: differential-geometry, stokes-theorem

Stoke’s theorem is that the total change over the boundary is equal to the sum/integral of the derivatives over the region. Written out like this: $$ \int_D df = \int_{\partial D}f$$
If D is the region and $\partial D$ is the boundary of that region.

I understand what the integral of the derivatives over the entire region means. What I don’t understand is how the total change over the boundary on the right is calculated when thinking in terms of abstract spaces like manifolds or even 2D space. Conceptually I’m also having trouble understanding what I’m supposed to look for along the boundary or what is even changing: direction, position or something else. It would be nice if I could get some help on this. Thanks!

Comment: I recomend to study first the historical [Gauss theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence_theorem) and the historical [Stokes theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem) in $\mathbb R^3$ . You need to understand what a surface integral and a line integral is. The generalized Stoke's theorem is a marvellous generalization of the former two due to Elie Cartan.

Comment: The easiest thing for you is to pick up a text on differential geometry (if you have  some basic understanding of manifold).

Comment: Stokes theorem is just a generalization of the fundamental theorem of calculus. If you can understand the fundamental theorem of calculus then you can understand Stokes theorem. In short: the difference between $df$ and $f$ is that the later contains all information that is needed to compute the original integral using just $\partial D$